# File searching in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want a function that takes a string argument (data) and breaks that string into words (word). Afterwards, it should take all the files in a directory, get each file name and check if all the words are present in the file name or not.
If present then print the name of the file and print "do you want to open it " if yes then print "opened" and break all the loops. If no then it should continue searching.

At the end, it should print whether the file is present or not in the directory.

Here's the code I wrote.

```
def file_search(data):
  data = data.split()

  for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/media/", topdown=False):
       word_match = True
       opened = False

       if not opened:

            for name in files:
                for word in data:
                    if word not in name:
                        word_match = False

                if word_match:
                    print "file found:" + name + "where path is" + root
                    print "do you want to open it "
                    answer = raw_input()
                    if answer == "yes" :
                        opened = True
                        print "file opened"
                        break
```

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing ? The stack traceback or error specifically

Comment: Utraksh no error is there . it runs successfully but didn't print anything . even when given file is present in the directory

Comment: That might be because you didnt call the function in your script, you have just declared it, Use `file_search("Name of file")` to call your function.

Comment: i was calling it from another file brother

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I fixed it.

```
def file_search2(name, name_words):
check = True
for word in name_words:
    if word not in name:
        check = False
        break

return check




def file_search(filename):
    file_found = False
    file_opened = False
    words = filename.split()

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/media/', topdown=False):

        for name in files:



            if file_search2(name, words) and file_opened == False:
                file_found = True
                print "file found :" + name
                print "Do you want to open the file:"
                answer = raw_input()
                if "yes" in answer:
                    file_opened = True
                    print "file opened successfully"

    if file_opened == False:
        print "file not found"



file_search("file name with space")
```